# can we give a <picture> element link to other page?

Tags: html

I have this kind of code:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="Img/material.jpg" media="(min-width: 401px)">
    <source srcset="Img/materialw400px.jpg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
    <img id="material" srcset="Img/material.jpg" alt="Material">
</picture>
```

the question is, can we give that picture a link to other page?

I've already tried using `<a>` tag before the `<picture>` tag and inside the tag but none of these is working.

Comment: Wrap with "a" works perfect http://jsbin.com/vemamidihu

Comment: it's weird,

already try with it before but fail, and try it again after read the comment and it's works perfectly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://php.net">
    <picture>
       <source media="(min-width: 401px)" srcset="Img/material.jpg"></source>
       <source media="(max-width: 400px)" srcset="Img/materialw400px.jpg"></source>
       <img alt="Material" srcset="Img/material.jpg" id="material">
    </picture> 
</a>
```

It works fine.

Comment: why do you close source with `</source>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the anchor `<a>` attribute with the addition of a 'target' attribute like this:

```
<a target="null" href="[url1]">
<picture>
    <source [label1]="(min-width: [x]px)" srcset="[url2]">
    </source> 
    <source [label1]="(max-width: [x]px)" srcset="[Url3]">
    </source>
    <img alt="[label2]" srcset="[url4]" id="[label2]">
</picture>
</a>
```

I don’t know why this wouldn’t work. I ran this and it worked fine.